# FragmentPagerAdapter getItem wrong position

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter

I've got strange problem with FramentPageAdapter

MainActivity.java

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class MainActivity<DashboardActivity> extends FragmentActivity implements     ActionBar.TabListener {
...
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(0)).setTabListener(this).setIcon(R.drawable.rating_good));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(1)).setTabListener(this).setIcon(R.drawable.action_search));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(2)).setTabListener(this).setIcon(R.drawable.action_search));
}
...
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null; 
        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Fragment0();  
            break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Fragment1();  
            break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Fragment2();  
            break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
    /*
     * Title
     */
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section0).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

public Fragment getItem(int position) return wrong position when i try to switch between 3 tabs. When i create app with 2 tabs only, everything work just fine. Adding more then 2 of them, creating strange problem. 
Switch from 0 to 1 position - works fine, switch from 1 to 0 - works fine, switch from 1 to 2 posiition - works fine, but, when i try to go back from 2 to 1 position, public Fragment getItem(int position) - int position return "0" instead of "1".
Does anyone help me with this ?

Comment: This seems like critical issue, any one has "correct solution" for this?

Answer (score 9):

Ok, I've found the solution.
First of all, the getItem "int position", doesn't indicate current display fragment. 
To display 3 or more tabs, without unload firts fragment You must added this line:

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

End of story...

Comment: this is a very bad advice.. you must not keep your fragments alive when they are not in use, so that's y android will call to finish it.
And by adding this line
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(count);
your asking android not to clear these unused fragment, think what happens when your fragment has loads of images..

Comment: @user2536592 did you resolve the problem i am facing the same problem public Fragment getItem(int i) call twice which give the wrong position i have 5 tabs with 5 fragments if(i>0){ i = i-1; } work but the problem is that last tab or fragment not been calling b/c position = position -1
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4); not  working for me

Answer (score 3):

You just need:

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        Log.d("test", "position = " + position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```

The `position` in `onPageSelected` is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I had had the same problem, and I used fragment inside each tabs;
So instead of

```
mViewPager.setAdapter(new MainTabs(getFragmentManager()));
```

use this one:

```
mViewPager.setAdapter(new MainTabs(getChildFragmentManager()));
```

Comment: Anyway to use getChildFragmentManager() using minSDK 14?

Comment: Cannot get getChildFragmentManager in support (Which is needed unless you're bleeding edge..)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has this issue, I solved it by not using the `position` given. Instead, I get a `List` of `Fragment` with `getSupportFragmentManager`, loop through, and check if the current `Fragment` is `instanceof` my desired `Fragment`.